# How to implement findbyid in frontend using mean stack

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

my route.js

```
router.get('/:id',(req,res,next)=>{
  University.findById(req.params.id, function (err, universities){
     if(err)
     {
       res.json(err);
     }
     else{
       res.json(universities);
     }
  });
});
```

this backend process working fine.but i don't know, how to implement in angular frontend.

university.service.ts

```
getSingleuniversities(id)
  {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/' + id).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

my singleuniversity.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UniversityService} from '../university.service';
import {University} from '../university';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-singleuniversity',
  templateUrl: './singleuniversity.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./singleuniversity.component.css']
})
export class SingleuniversityComponent implements OnInit {
  universities: University[];

  constructor(private universityService:UniversityService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}
  getSingleuniversities(id:any){
  this.universityService. getSingleuniversities(id)
        .subscribe( universities => 
        this.universities = universities);
      }
}
```

singleuniversity.component.html

```
<li>{{university.universityname}}</li>
```

In singleuniversity.component.html,i am getting error ,

```
SingleuniversityComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'universityname' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (SingleuniversityComponent.html:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:10872)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10248)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10484)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10426)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10249)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10484)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:10447)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10244)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10484)
```

how to solve this one. i don't know where i did mistake please help me, if anyone know.

Comment: `university` will be an array, not an object, meaning you cant do `university.universityname`

Comment: Is that `li` HTML tag part of an `*ngFor` loop? Because from your code, there is no variable called `university`, only `universities`

Comment: how i call that universityname.. plz tell me

Comment: You need to determine first of all whether your service returns an array or not. The function is called `getSingleuniversities`, and the backend looks like it should only return a single value, but you've typed it as an array

Comment: i couldn't get it..where i did mistake.. plz tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken your service should return an Observable and should be more like this:

```
getSingleuniversities(id): Observable<University[]>{
    return this.http.get<University[]>('http://localhost:3000/api/' + id);
}
```

The method should be then called like this:

```
this.universityService.getSingleuniversities(id).subscribe( 
 (universities: University[]) => this.universities = universities,
 (err: any) => console.log(err));
}
```

Your list items should be displayed inside a loop like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let university of universities">{{university.universityname}}</li>
```

This way the list displays no items at all as long as it is waiting for the request to respond and should throw no undefined error.

Comment: i get error in 'get<University[]>' like Expected 0 type arguments but got 1. why i get this error

Comment: Thats strange, I don't get that error. Could you show your service.ts file?

Comment: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {University} from './university';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UniversityService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  getUniversities()
  {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/usa').map(res => res.json().universities);
  }
  getSingleuniversities(id): Observable<University[]>{
    return this.http.get<University[]>('http://localhost:3000/api/' + id);
}

}

Comment: Try importing `HttpClient` instead of `Http` and use `private http: HttpClient` in the constructor.

Comment: can i change anything in singleuniversity.component.ts? now i didn't get any error but universityname is not display

Comment: I edited my answer how to properly use the service method in the component.ts. If this doesn't work you could `console.log(universities)` in your request and check if it is structured the way you want.

Comment: i got its work fine now . thank you so much for reply. i have one doubt that i have nested data in mongodb like ug.tutionfees. how to give this type of data in model class.. plz tell me

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean, but if you `console.log` your respone you can check exactly how your Json reply is structured. If you see how it is nested in the Json you know how to access it.